# how to use elasticsearch grails plugins with mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, grails, elasticsearch

I am using both elasticsearch plugins and mongodb plugins in my grails project.
The application.yml file is like:

```
mongodb:
    host: "localhost"
    port: 27017
    databaseName: "search"

elasticSearch:
    client:
        mode: local
    disableAutoIndex: false
    datastoreImpl: mongoDatastore
    bulkIndexOnStartup: true
    index:
        store.type: mmapfs
```

I commented out the hibernate in build.grdle because I need to use mongodb as your primary datastore.

```
//compile "org.grails.plugins:hibernate4"
```

Then the mongodb worked well since I could use

```
MyDomain.findByXXXXX()
```

to query the data in my mongodb.
But when I used

```
def result = MyDomain.search("${query}")
```

or

```
def result = elasticSearchService.search("${query}")
```

and print the result, it showed

```
[total:0, searchResults:[]]
```

That seemed the elasticSearch plugins worked but it did not connect to the mongodb.I wonder whether `datastoreImpl: mongoDatastore` worked or not.

Is there something I am missing? Appreciate your help in advance.

Thank You

Comment: do you have the `static searchable = true` in your model object ?

Comment: can you upgrade the plugin to v1.0.0.2 (at least)

Comment: i got another issue: when i have the `static searchable = true`, it said `Error configuring dynamic methods for plugin [elasticsearch:1.0.0]: Cannot add new static method [search] for arguments [[class java.lang.String]]. It already exists!`.Then i found it was cause by the conflict of `MyDomain.search()` between MongoDB and Elasticsearch.But it was so weird because i have the code `static searchable = { propertyName: ....}` in the very beginning and at that time the confict did not happen. @Frédéric Henri

Comment: see https://github.com/noamt/elasticsearch-grails-plugin/issues/145

Comment: i fixed the confict by change the method name to `esSearch`, many thanks.But i still got `[total:0, searchResults:[]]` in `MyDomain.search("${query}")`.

Comment: so if you change the name of the method you now need to have `MyDomain.esSearch("${query}")`

Comment: Thanks for replied again.i am sorry for typing wrong word, i did have `esSearch` and got no result. what possible reasons may lead to this issue?@Frédéric Henri